# Problem with & and double quotes in my Android app

Tags: android, special-characters

in my app I am facing following two problems

1. I am trying to show some text from strings.xml file stored in res/values folder. The problem is whenever I enter the `&` it shows an error as follows:

   Multiple annotations found at this line:
       - The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity 
        reference.
       - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

When I remove it the error gets cleared. how to use such special characters in my app

2. When I click a button in my app it hits an url and in return I am getting an return data as follows

   ```
   <img src="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test.php%3Fcode_hash%3Da8c159f35af&amp;guid=ON"/>
   ```

I want to get this url removing the `img src="`

I tried using the replacewith("","");

But here I am unable to give the `"` within the double quotes.

How to solve the above issues?

Comment: Answer posted below about your first issue.  Can you explain further what you are trying to do with the string replacement in the second part of your question?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In XML strings for & (ampersand) you need to use `&amp;` and quotes (single or double) need to be escaped,

```
<string name="with_amp">I, Me &amp; Myself</string>
<string name="with_quotes>Single quote \' and Double quotes \"</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of & you have to use & check in the following statements

test&

```
<string name="url">http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/test.php%3Fcode_hash%3Da8c159f35af&amp;guid=ON</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the symbol `&` in your `strings.xml` file, you need to use the appropriate [XML character entity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).
For `ampersand`, use `&amp;`.